# Field Service Lightning (FSL) Scheduling

Tags: lightning-experience, fields, field-service-lightning, schedule, fieldservice

I am learning FSL and trying to schedule Service Appointments in Field Service Gantt. I am not able to drag or locate my Service Appointments in Gantt. There is a warning sign with my Service Appointments with different warning messages.

For Example: 
1- Resource Territory Not Found 
2- Earliest Start Permitted 
3- Working Hour 
4- Match Territory 
5- Resource Availability 
How can i fix them? 
Thanks in Advance!

[image: Field Service Lightning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you have mentioned Resource Territory, Earliest Start Permitted, Working Hour, Match Territory, Resource Availability - are called Work Rules under Scheduling Policies.

The Work Rules differs based on the Scheduling Policy you choose to Schedule SA.

For an example - a scheduling policy called "Soft Boundaries" - does not include "Match Territory" in scheduling a SA.

Will tell you what could be the issues in your case

1- Resource Territory Not Found - Make Sure you are assigning technician to the exact 
 active Service Territory which is mentioned in the SA. If it is empty, populate an active service territory in SA and drag and drop the SA to the correct Service Territory.

2- Earliest Start Permitted - Make sure you are assigning SA ON / Later the date which is mentioned as Earliest Start Permitted Date in SA. If you tend to assign early - you might receive this error.

3- Working Hour - You have to set operating hour for the Territory and the concern Territory Technician

4- Match Territory - Assigning Right Territory to right Technician

5- Resource Availability - There will be start date field in Service Resource - it is the date the Service Resource is going to start working in FSL. So if you are assigning SA whose start date earlier than the Service Resource's Start Date - you will get this error.